# How to call one controller on every page

Tags: opencart2.x

If I want to load controller or module on every page , Should I load controller every time?
My question is what is the best practice to load controller on every page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You need to load a model inside of another model, You could load it the very same way using `$this->load->model('my_module/my_model');`.

If You need to load a model inside of template file or other custom PHP script, look at the index.php file where the Registry is instantiated - You would need to instantiate it the same way. So Your custom code could look like:

```
$registry = new Registry();
$my_model = $registry->load->model('my_module/my_model');
$my_model->customFunction();
```

In this way you can do it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in opencart. For example If I want to load the footer I have to load the footer controller  $this->load->controller('common/header'); inside one controller (Ex: home). But If I inside another another controller (Ex: Information) I have to load footer controller again. What should I do?

Comment: you can load as $this->load->controller('common/header'); as you want in any controller.

Comment: But I have to load it on every controller , If I want to show it all page.Is it right